# Search part of a string in a file

Tags: string, bash, shell, search, scripting

Suppose I have a variable $str1

```
str1="20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|"
```

What I want to do is search that part in the file. The file contains, for example:

```
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|
20140121-21:50:28|Nikko|Real|9065887272.000000|Mar 21|
20140121-22:22:53|Czarina|Revilla|9999999999.000000|Jan 21|
```

The output should be:

```
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|
```

I don't know if it matters, but this is the actual code snippet I am using yad:

```
selected=$(yad --title=Contacts --width=200 --height=200 \
               --button=DISPLAY:2 --list \
               --separator="|" --column=ID:NUM --column=List \
               "${items[@]}" --hide-column=1 --button=ADD:10 )
req=$?

#BUTTON HANDLER:
if [ $req = 10 ]; then
    formdata=$(yad --title="Add Contact"   \
    --form --field="FIRST NAME" --separator="|"   \
     --field="LAST NAME"   \
     --field="CONTACT #:NUM"   \
     --field="Birthday (Mon Day):DT"  --date-format="%b %d" \
     "" "" "!09000000000..09999999999!11."
    )

        echo "$contactid|$formdata" >> contactlist.txt

elif [ $req = 2 ]; then
    grep "$selected" contactlist.txt #This is my problem

fi
```

and it doesn't output anything

Update:
Finally know what the heck is the problem tried to `echo $selected` and it outputs `20140121|Adrian Perez|` meaning it really ISN'T in the file. Haaa! I'm such a mess! -_-

Comment: Have you considered `grep "$str1" file` ?

Comment: Not sure what I'm going to do but I tried `grep "$selected" contactlist.txt` but it doesn't work! @cnicutar

Comment: @joanne_ Why are you using $selected when the search string is $str1?

Comment: @Trenin woops! sorry my bad! that's the variable i used in my code the code above is just an example!

Comment: @joanne_: See comment from cnicutar. Did you try grep?

Comment: @anubhava I tried grep "$str1" contactlist.txt as I have mentioned above.. but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with `grep`? It's a tool designed specifically for such purposes and incredibly powerful as well.

To provide you with a simple introduction to the most basic usage: `grep <pattern> <file>` (or `cat <file> | grep <pattern>` if you insist on using a pipe). In your example that would be `grep "20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|" foo` assuming `foo` is the name of the file. This produces exactly what you want - a line containing the pattern.

Comment: yes that worked.. but that is actually not what I'm looking for. :( I want to be able to use the variable `$str1` so that i can change the value

Comment: Do you intend to use it in a script or in interactive shell? If the latter, then you can do `export str1="20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|"` and then call `grep "$str1" foo` for the very same effect as above. You can do the same in a script, except there's no need for using `export`, you can just state `str1="20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|"` and you're good to go :)

Comment: Thanks @Erathiel for your help! :) I found that there's something wrong with the variable itself, that's why it didn't output anything. Hha stupid me!

Comment: For testing/debugging purposes you could simply add `echo $?` in the line after `grep "$selected" contactlist.txt`. The variable `$?` in bash stores the exit code of the last command. If it's `0` then everything was OK (e.g. the searched pattern was found), if it's non-zero it means that either nothing was found or some error occurred. That would help you see what is happening :)

Comment: i appreciate your help! i'm actually using yad for the interface and it just made everything complicated haha! see my update above if you haven't seen it already

Answer (score 0):

use grep

details on usage here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep
or check the man pages run> man grep from the shell

an example assuming you data is in a file called test_file.txt

```
grep "20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|" test_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ cat contactlist.txt 
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|
20140121-21:50:28|Nikko|Real|9065887272.000000|Mar 21|
20140121-22:22:53|Czarina|Revilla|9999999999.000000|Jan 21|
$ echo $str1
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|
$ grep "$str1" contactlist.txt 
20140121-21:48:26|Joanne Frances|Perez|9173046751.000000|Mar 31|
$
```